# InfoWindows with OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers-3

I'm currenlty working with OpenLayers and I want to make something similar to a infoWindow.

I read this example : http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.2/examples/popup.html , but I see it as a "dirty" solution, comparing to the older version of OpenLayers, which had a class for PopUp and you created the object directly in javascript, and I was wondering if there is another solution in the current version.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the ol3 core developers considered this: popups is something that very often needs to be customized to the user's needs.  The example demonstrates how one could do it, but there are as many other good solutions as there are implementations.  My point is: it's okay to customize your own.

Comment: What about a feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see https://github.com/walkermatt/ol3-popup? It can be as easy as:

```js
var popup = new ol.Overlay.Popup;
map.addOverlay(popup);

// to show something
popup.show(coord, html);
// hiding
popup.hide();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work with the latest `ol` package.